# Can std::bind1st be used to convert void (*)(void*,int) to void (*)(int)?

Tags: c++, stdbind

I have a function `void f (void*, int);`, that is used as a callback function. The caller expects `void (*)(int)`. Can I use `std::bind1st` to convert one to another? Is there any way to do this without using C++ 11 `std::bind`, just `std::bind1st`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Although `std::bind1st()` creates a function object with a call operator taking and `int`, it is *not* a `void(*)(int)`. The only way to turn a `void(*)(void*, int)` into a `void(*)(int)` is to have a forwarding function which obtains the `void*` from global resources, e.g.,

```
static void* data = 0; // probably needs to be set to a more suitable value
void f_forward(int value) {
    f(data, value);
}
```

Anybody providing a callback which doesn't take a user-defined context, e.g., in the C-like interface a `void*` which is just passed through, didn't think too hard about the interface.

Comment: Indeed. I was hoping to avoid a global / static variable. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @violetgiraffe The other way is to write self modifying code, which is both non portable and lower level than C++.  Basically get a writable page from the OS, blit a known function with a constant embedded in the machine code, modify that constant, mark the page as read only and executable, then take a pointer to the function with the 'hard-coded' `void*`.  And yes, this is doable on many platforms, it is just rarely wise.  Use a global, and if you need more than one, use a set of `N` and a global array, and assert that you use no more than `N`.